# How can I access the options of an Angular select element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write an attribute directive that will be used to enhance a `select` element. I need to access the `option` children of the `select` element as part of this enhancement (so I'd like to be able to access them in the `link` function).

For example, here is a very basic template:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="i for i in data" enhanced></select>
</div>
```

A very basic controller:

```
var t = angular.module("test", []);
t.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
    ];
    $scope.selected = $scope.data[0];
});
```

And finally a very basic directive:

```
t.directive("enhanced", function () {
    return function ($scope, $element) {
        console.log($element.find("option").length); // Always 0
    };
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/vx2c3/) containing that complete example.

The problem is that inside the `link` function, the `ng-options` directive has not yet executed and the `select` element is still empty. Is there a way I can defer the execution of my directive until the `ng-options` directive is complete? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a $timeout inside your directive.

```
t.directive("enhanced", function ($timeout) {
    return function ($scope, $element) {
        $timeout(function(){
            console.log($element.find("option").length); // 3
        })
    };
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDJDM/1/)

Another option is using a watcher:

```
t.directive("enhanced", function () {
    return function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.$watch('selected', function () {
            console.log($element.find("option").length); // 3
        });
    };
});
```

The only problem with this approach is that it will run anytime the expression changes so you will have to unwatch after the first time.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uz95/)

Comment: I could, but that is not very nice. There must be a better way to handle this.

Comment: What about watching an expression?, the problem with this approach is that it will run anytime the expression changes so you will have to unwatch after the first time.

Comment: The `$watch` may be what I'm looking for. I did try that, but in a different way. Thanks for your help, I've been struggling to get into an Angular way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The options are [currently rendered](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js#L397) in a `$scope.$watch` statement. Thus there is no way to see the list of options in the `link` function since the `watch` will be called later.

The only way to introspect the list of options before that time is to parse `attr.ngOptions` yourself and get the list when you want it.